# Difference between two dates with subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, subquery

I'm trying to calculate the difference between two dates on Postgres. First I get the dates:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
            to_char(to_timestamp(t.time/1000000), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS initial_date
    FROM
            book.ticket AS t

    WHERE status = 'planning'
) AS initial_date,

(
    SELECT 
            to_char(to_timestamp(t.time/1000000), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS final_date
    FROM
            book.ticket AS t

    WHERE status = 'closed'
) AS final_date
```

And then I would like to do something like that to calculate the difference between the recovered dates previously:

```
SELECT DATE_PART('day', final_date::timestamp - initial_date::timestamp)
```

But I don't know how to put this last part (that one that calculates) together with the others queries. Can someone help me?

Comment: That should work just fine if you omit the `to_char`.

Comment: How many rows do the first and second queries return? Single one each? Yeah, remove that `to_char`.

Comment: Hello, everyone

My propose is to calculate how long (in days) a task on my book table tooks between planning and closed. So first i get the date when the task is with status "planning" and them i get the date when changed to "closed" and try to calculate the diff. If i run the first and second queries isolated, brings me more than one result

Comment: I have the date and time, like that: '2018-07-06 15:30:40+00'. As related on postgree site, the function date_part should be used like this model: 

date_part('day', timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40'). 

So i tried this and worked: 

SELECT DATE_PART('day', '2018-07-06 15:30:40+00'::timestamp - '2018-07-10 15:30:40+00'::timestamp)

If you pain attention on my example above, i put the date on quotes because if i don't do it, i will get an error. The transformation toChar() that i made on my code is because of this rule on date_part function. That's why i can't omit the to_char

Comment: Please don't put *SOLVED* in question's title. Approve for an answer is enough. I've removed that phrase from title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, guys! After all this discussion i solved my problem. I will post the code bellow. Thanks for helping me, everyone's opinion was important!

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.initial_date, t2.id, t2.final_date, t2.final_date - t1.initial_date as dif
FROM (

        (
        SELECT 
            t.id,
            to_timestamp(t.time/1000000) AS initial_date
        FROM
            book.ticket AS t
        WHERE status = 'planning' 
        )  t1

JOIN   (
        SELECT 
            t.id,
            to_timestamp(t.time/1000000) AS final_date
        FROM
            book.ticket AS t
        WHERE status = 'closed'  
       )  t2
ON t1.id  = t2.id 
)
```